# What Factors affect Google Auto Complete

Tags: google

What factors affect Google auto complete?

It's not sheer volume of traffic, it seems it's a mixture of traffic volume and bounce rate?

Anyone with insight of how to remove the scam term, please can you shine some light as well.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by scam term?

Comment: @toomanyairmiles the scam term they are referring to is probably the word scam coming up after a company, brand, or website name. I assume it has to do with someones reputation which they're trying to fix and get the "company xyz scam" out of Google auto complete. Just a guess though

Comment: @Anagio good guess.. tricky one really, depends on if there is actually scam behavior going on.

Comment: @toomanyairmiles yea, I didn't want to assume it's their own reputation so I said `someones`. I doubt there is any way to get these words removed, other than to inject other terms into auto complete and have them appear way above the scam phrase. Maybe get a lot of unique searches using other friendly phrases with company xyz and cross your fingers.

Answer (score 2):

As with most things related to Google's search results this information is not publicly available. It probably has a lot to do with link popularity and search volume but I'm sure there are more factors involved.

If the speculation in the comments above are correct your best bet is to see which pages rank well for that term and either try to outrank them with a positive message of your own, or if they are slanderous, use legal means to have them taken down.

Answer (score 0):

In our experience and testing, we have discovered three overriding factors that drive Google Autocomplete:

1. **Search Volume and Searcher Location**:
   The amount of searches performed for a name/keyword along with the location of the searchers
2. **Keyword and Phrase Appearance**:
   The total number of mentions of the words on third-party websites, blogs, and forums
3. **Social Media Mentions**:
   The amount and consistency of mentions on social media platforms such as Twitter, Facebook, LinkedIn and Google+

The algorithm also contains a time tracking component that factors in the freshness of queries and content. This component ensures that new, trending searches are included as well.

You can take a look at the autocomplete values for your brand or any other search term with our custom [Google Autocomplete tool](https://gofishdigital.com/autocomplete/).